# Concatenate two layers in keras, tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to build the below architecture of neural network layers

[image]

I have a cnn layer:

```
cnn1 = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((32, 32, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu')
    ]
)
```

And module:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense

'''Module 1'''
module1_left = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((28, 28, 32)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
module1_middle = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((28, 28, 32)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
module1_right = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((28, 28, 32)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
module1 = keras.layers.concatenate([module1_left.outputs[0], module1_middle.outputs[0], module1_right.outputs[0]], axis=-1)
```

Then I try to combine cnn1 and module 1, by `cnn1.add(module1)`, here's the error for the last line:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_27/Identity:0", shape=(None, 28, 28, 128), dtype=float32)
```

Then I try another approach to concatenate:

```
module1 = Concatenate([module1_left, module1_middle, module1_right])
```

Then I get the error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs
```

Please let me know what's wrong with those approaches. Thank you!

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (most flexible,elegant) solution is to use the `Functional API` in `Keras`.

Here is a working solution. Notice I am using the `Model()` (Functional API) instantiation and not `Sequential()`:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
image_input = keras.layers.Input((32, 32, 3))
output_cnn_1 = cnn1(image_input)
output_left = module1_left(output_cnn_1)
output_middle = module1_middle(output_cnn_1)
output_right = module1_right(output_cnn_1)
concatenated_output = keras.layers.Concatenate()([output_left,output_middle,output_right])
final_model = Model(inputs=image_input, outputs=concatenated_output)
final_model.summary()



Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_29 (InputLayer)           [(None, 32, 32, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_11 (Sequential)      (None, 28, 28, 32)   2432        input_29[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_12 (Sequential)      (None, 28, 28, 32)   1056        sequential_11[8][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_13 (Sequential)      (None, 28, 28, 64)   19552       sequential_11[8][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_14 (Sequential)      (None, 28, 28, 32)   1056        sequential_11[8][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_15 (Concatenate)    (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           sequential_12[8][0]              
                                                                 sequential_13[8][0]              
                                                                 sequential_14[8][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,096
Trainable params: 24,096
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Where the definition has slightly changed (we **do not** declare the `input` for each of the modules, since **we are using the output of the cnn1**).

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

cnn1 = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu')
    ]
)

'''Module 1'''
module1_left = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
module1_middle = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
module1_right = keras.Sequential([
    layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
    ]
)
```